# Error in TexStudio: "Build and View"

Tags: pdftex, pdf, l3build

I am facing an issue when i click on "Build and view" this error appears.

Error: Could not start the command: pdflatex.exe -synctex=1 -interaction=nonstopmode "elsarticle-template".tex

Is there anyone who can guide?

Comment: Standard question for this error: Have you actually installed a LaTeX dist? TeXStudio is not enough. If you have LaTeX installed, then which LaTeX and which operating system. (BTW: the l3build tag is not relevant to this question, similar for the pdf tag)

Comment: i have installed mictex and then texstudio.

Comment: and which operating system? Can you run pdflatex from a terminal/dos prompt?